# Difficulty with scraping next button

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here is the script, I attempted to write, but cannot figure out another way to write it, so that it works.

This seems to be the only issue with my script.

Any help or tips on different methods for pagination or web scraping "cheat sheets" would be more than welcome.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer
from time import sleep

all_names = []

base_url = "https://palmettostatearmory.com"
url = "/sights-optics-scopes.html?p=1"


with open("PSA_sights_optics_scopes.csv", "w") as csv_file:   
    csv_writer = writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(["Title", "Price", "Item Url", "Image"])


    while url:

        res = requests.get(f"{base_url}{url}")
        print(f"Now Scraping {base_url}{url}...")

        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
        names = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "media listing"})
        #the whole element that is selected

        #looping through all of the names with a for loop
        for name in names:
            title = name.find("h2", {"class": "product-name"}).text.strip()
            price = name.find("span", {"class": "price-value"}).text.strip()
            img = name.find("img").get("src")
            csv_writer.writerow([title, price, img])

        #scraping the next page button
        next_btn = soup.find(class_="next i-next").get("href")

        url = next_btn if next_btn else None
        #tells it to click the next page button and then if there is not one, it wont run anymore, making the text above false and stops it
        sleep(4)
```

Here is the Error that I am getting in terminal:

```
line 34, in <module>
next_btn = soup.find(class_="next i-next").get("href")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

This is what I'm seeing on the website:

```
<li>
<a class="next i-next" href="[https://palmettostatearmory.com/sights-optics-scopes.html?p=2](https://palmettostatearmory.com/sights-optics-scopes.html?p=2)" title="Next">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
next_btn = soup.find("a", class_="next i-next").get("href") or 
next_btn = soup.find("a", {"class": "next i-next"}).get("href")
```

Comment: Hi, I attempted what you suggested and had no luck. I updated the post with my current code and more information. Hopefully that will give you more info. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

*How about the following*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<a class="next i-next" href="[https://palmettostatearmory.com/sights-optics-scopes.html?p=2](https://palmettostatearmory.com/sights-optics-scopes.html?p=2)" title="Next">'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

Comment: Hi, could you please take a look at the updated code that I provided. I attempted to input the code that you provided but it pulled all links within the site.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are getting page content? 
res = requests.get('https://palmettostatearmory.com/sights-optics-scopes.html?p=1') gets a page with captcha as far as I can see. First check what you get as response